# Failed to include _wfopen in project

Tags: c, static-libraries, freepascal, lazarus

I am trying to include a static lib (.a) file built with mingw in the lazarus project but failed to do so. Because the lib contains a function.

```
_wfopen() from stdio.h/wchar.h
```

I had already included

```
{$LinkLib gcc}
{$LinkLib mylib}

Function soo(...); cdecl; external;
```

Headers used in the static lib are

```
stdio.h
wchar.h
stdlib.h
```

What is wrong here. please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the main C runtime, "c".